# Checking bits of data from JSON in Python

Tags: python, json

I want to be able to check if a JSON array has a piece of data that meets criteria. I am learning Python and JSONs are somewhat new to me.
This is what I have so far... The idea is that as long as the 'contact_count' < 0 or == to 0 in this case that it wound recursively run that function until its false

```
def instantMessage():
    data = json.loads(jSon)
    while data[1]['contact_count'] == 0:
        instantMessage()


jSon = {u'contact_list': [], u'contact_count': 0}
```

I appreciate your help ahead of time!

Comment: What is your JSON structure? What's stored in `jSon` is a Python dictionary.

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure I'm kinda nieve here :/ I might know what to look for if you point me in the right direction

Comment: @JC Really, you haven't provided enough information to go on so it's hard to know how to help. It would help if you could provide a sample input (a JSON array), and what you expect the results to be. The beginning of the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module documentation shows some examples of using JSON in Python.

Comment: `jSon` isn't a JSON, it is a `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if your JSON object is not changing, this will result in an infinite loop:

```
def instantMessage():
    data = json.loads(jSon)
    while data.get('contact_count') == 0:
        instantMessage()
```